# Awaiting data from Serial Port in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, serial-port

I have an application that receives data from a wireless radio using RS-232. These radios use an API for communicating with multiple clients. To use the radios I created a library for communicate with them that other software can utilize with minimal changes from a normal SerialPort connection. The library reads from a SerialPort object and inserts incoming data into different buffers depending on the radio it receives from. Each packet that is received contains a header indicating its length, source, etc.

I start by reading the header, which is fixed-length, from the port and parsing it. In the header, the length of the data is defined before the data payload itself, so once I know the length of the data, I then wait for that much data to be available, then read in that many bytes.

Example (the other elements from the header are omitted):

```
// Read header
byte[] header = new byte[RCV_HEADER_LENGTH];
this.Port.Read(header, 0, RCV_HEADER_LENGTH);

// Get length of data in packet
short dataLength = header[1];
byte[] payload = new byte[dataLength];

// Make sure all the payload of this packet is ready to read
while (this.Port.BytesToRead < dataLength) { }

this.Port.Read(payload, 0, dataLength);
```

Obviously the empty while port is bad. If for some reason the data never arrives the thread will lock. I haven't encountered this problem yet, but I'm looking for an elegant way to do this. My first thought is to add a short timer that starts just before the while-loop, and sets an abortRead flag when it elapses that would break the while loop, like this:

```
// Make sure all the payload of this packet is ready to read
abortRead = false;
readTimer.Start();
while (this.Port.BytesToRead < dataLength && !abortRead) {}
```

This code needs to handle a constant stream of incoming data as quickly as it can, so keeping overhead to a minimum is a concern, and am wondering if I am doing this properly.

Comment: I don't know/use C#, but the general rule for *"keeping overhead to a minimum"* is to make as few system calls as possible.  IOW get as much data as possible per read request.  Don't try to use individual read requests as part of the parsing algorithm (e.g. read header then read variable data).  Simply read everything into buffer(s), then parse it

Comment: Initial data from a uart may not be valid so you usually have to flush the bad data at the beginning.  I suspect this is what is happening in your case.  The byte count you are getting in first message is wrong and locking up the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to run this while loop, the method `Read` would either fill the buffer for you or would throw a `TimeoutException` if buffer wasn't filled within the `SerialPort.ReadTimeout` time (which you can adjust to your needs).

But some general remark - your while loop would cause intensive CPU work for nothing, in the few milliseconds it would take the data to arrive you would have thousends of this while loop iterations, you should've add some `Thread.Sleep` inside.

Comment: I knew I was probably overthinking it.

Comment: Use SpinWait, not Thread.Sleep. SpinWait has been specifically designed fort hese situations, os multi-CPU friendly and will yield to another thread on demand (unlike Sleep, which will always yield).

Comment: @Sefe Correct me if I'm wrong please, but I think SpinWait designed for waiting for CPU operations (<<1ms) and when waiting for IO operations (which might be 20ms and even more) it is better to use Thread.Sleep (and to yield on each iteration).

Comment: It's basically the while loop, except it will yield instead of continuing to loop for a longer time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truly adress this problem, you need to run the code in the background. There are different options to do that; you can start a thread, you start a `Task` or you can use `async await`.

To fully cover all options, the answer would be endless. If you use threads or tasks with the default scheduler and your wait time is expected to be rather short, you can use `SpinWait.SpinUntil` instead of your while loop. This will perform better than your solution:

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => this.Port.BytesToRead >= dataLength);
```

If you are free to use `async await`, I would recommend this solution, since you need only a few changes to your code. You can use `Task.Delay` and in the best case you pass a `CancellationToken` to be able to cancel your operation:

```
try {
    while (this.Port.BytesToRead < dataLength) {
        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
    }
}
catch(OperationCancelledException) {
    //Cancellation logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do this asynchronously with the `SerialPort` `DataReceived` event.

```
// Class fields
private const int RCV_HEADER_LENGTH = 8;
private const int MAX_DATA_LENGTH = 255;

private SerialPort Port;

private byte[] PacketBuffer = new byte[RCV_HEADER_LENGTH + MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
private int Readi = 0;
private int DataLength = 0;


// In your constructor
this.Port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);


private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Read all available bytes.
    int len = Port.BytesToRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    Port.Read(data, 0, len);

    // Go through each byte.
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // Add the next byte to the packet buffer.
        PacketBuffer[Readi++] = data[i];

        // Check if we've received the complete header.
        if (Readi == RCV_HEADER_LENGTH)
        {
            DataLength = PacketBuffer[1];
        }

        // Check if we've received the complete data.
        if (Readi == RCV_HEADER_LENGTH + DataLength)
        {
            // The packet is complete add it to the appropriate buffer.

            Readi = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should add that my code is in a function that gets called when the DataReceived event fires. The Received Data Threshold for firing the event is set to the length of the header. That way I know I have a full header to work with, and can check if the rest of the data exists from there.